# Track email sent to a specific address in Exchange 07

Tags: exchange-2007, troubleshooting

I have SBS 08 with Exchange 07. Domain users have several email addresses pointing to their mail box. For example John Smith: jsmith@..., john.smith@..., smith.john@...

I want to track emails sent to one and only one of these addresses. It seems like the troubleshooting tool in Exchange is only able to track email sent to the mail box, whatever the address used.

The purpose is to determine if emails have ever been sent to one of those addresses so I can clean this up.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I don't specifically know if SBS allows this, but for straight up Exchange your best bet is to examine the Transport Logs themselves. The actual tracking logs are kept in `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft\Exchange Server\TransportRoles\Logs\MessagTracking`. Examining those logs directly will tell you if it has happened. From the CMD prompt, this command would probably do it for you:

`find "jsmith@..." *.LOG`

That'll let you know if that string shows up anywhere in the transport logs, however far back they go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I checked those files, I only have a month of logs split in about 20 logs files, no more. Where can I configure the logs so it keep more tracking information ?

Comment: Again, this may not be true for SBS 08. You can set this from the Exchange Powershell environment: `set-transportserver -MessageTrackingLogMaxAge 45.00:00:00` would set it to keep 45 days worth.

Comment: Thx, that'll help me for the future, if someone knows how to use the troubleshooting tool to search only for 1 adress, it would be great.